# How to push VC from child VC?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller, snapkit

I have three UIViewControllers. First one is `MainViewController`. MainViewController has TabView and, under TabView, childView (UIView). Depending on picked tab, childViewController is opened (on childView). `childViewController` has TableView. I want to enable when you **pick cell** on that TableView, to **push new UIViewController** (let's call it `EventDetailViewController`) and to be visible on **full screen** using  UINavigationController (without TabView from MainViewController). How to achieve that?
I use SnapKit, so everything is programatically.

Comment: That can be confusing navigation... you might be better off ***presenting*** the "detail" view controller using `.modalPresentationStyle` of `.fullScreen` or `.overFullScreen`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property of your detail view controller to true. [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-hide-the-tab-bar-when-a-view-controller-is-shown) is a short blogpost on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

Instantiate UITabBarController with UINavigationController. Then, push it to the navigationController that Tabbar belongs to. This way, you can push the tabbar and there is no need for a present.

If you are using a storyboard, you can embed the UITabBarController in a UINavigationController for the tabbar.

Example:

```
final class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstViewController = UIViewController()
    let secondViewController = UIViewController()
    
    firstViewController.title = "First"
    secondViewController.title = "Second"
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
    
    self.viewControllers = [firstViewController, secondViewController]
    
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = navigationController
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    // Push to Navigation Controller
    let thirdViewController = UIViewController()
    thirdViewController.title = "Third"
    navigationController.pushViewController(thirdViewController, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: The tab controller should not be in a nav controller. Each tab should have its own nav controller as needed.

Comment: @HangarRash I agree too but my solution is possible. Each flow should have its own navigationController as well as its tabbar.